# Context menu with more options in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Currently I already have a Context menu setup that is triggered when right clicking on highlighted text, but I'd like to make it a bit more advanced with more options for the menu.

What I'm wanting is basically what LastPass has here:

[image: here]

Where you right click the main menu option, and more options will pop up.

How can I do this?
My current code is below

```js
var contextMenuItem = {
  "id": "123",
  "title": "Title",
  "contexts": ["selection"]
}

chrome.contextMenus.create(contextMenuItem);

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(onClickHandler);
function onClickHandler(info, tab) {
  console.log(info.selectionText);
};
```

Comment: See the [demo extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:contextmenu) - simply add the new items with `parentId` property set to the previously added item's id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. get the permissions in `manifest.json`

```
    {
        ...,
        "permissions": [
          "contextMenus"
        ]
    }
```

2. `chrome.contentMenus.create` func

```
    chrome.contextMenus.create({
        type: "checkbox",
        id: "google_page_translate_demo_0x00",
        title: "Google Page Translate 0x00",
        checked: false,
        contexts: ["all"]
    }, function(){console.log('0x00 done')}
    )
    chrome.contextMenus.create({
        type: "normal",
        id: "google_page_translate_demo_0x01",
        title: "Google Page Translate 0x01",
        checked: false,
        contexts: ["all"]
    }, function(){console.log('0x01 done')}
    )
    chrome.contextMenus.create({
        type: "radio",
        id: "google_page_translate_demo_0x02",
        title: "Google Page Translate 0x02",
        checked: true,
        contexts: ["all"]
    }, function(){console.log('0x02 done')}
    )
    chrome.contextMenus.create({
        type: "separator",
        id: "google_page_translate_demo_0x03",
        title: "Google Page Translate 0x03",
        checked: true,
        contexts: ["all"]
    }, function(){console.log('0x03 done')}
    )
    chrome.contextMenus.create({
        type: "normal",
        id: "google_page_translate_demo_0x04",
        title: "Google Page Translate 0x04",
        checked: true,
        parentId: "google_page_translate_demo_0x01",
        contexts: ["all"]
    }, function(){console.log('0x04 done')}
    )

    chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(onClickHandler);
    function onClickHandler(o, t) {
      console.log(o);
      console.log(t);
    };
```

3. done
   [image]